# When playing Talisman as the assassin, can I assassinate creatures I encounter following the draw of a card?

Tags: talisman

When playing Talisman Revised 4th Edition as the [assassin](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Assassin_(Character)), can I assassinate creatures I encounter following the draw of a card? Or is the assassination limited to when I, the assassin, decide to purposefully attack a creature or a character?

The character chard and the [linked wiki](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Assassin_(Character)) merely say:

> - You may assassinate when you attack a character or creature. You cannot assassinate when you are attacked by another character. When you assassinate, battle takes place as normal except that your victim may not roll a die to add to his Strength. If you win, you must force the loser to lose 1 life; you cannot take an Object or gold instead.
> - You may not assassinate while at the Crown of Command.

An extension to this question is: can the assassin assassinate the [pitfiends](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Pits_(Base_Game_Board)) and the [werewolf](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Werewolf_Den) in the inner region?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official errata (linked [here](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/27/ff/27ff9a68-fd15-437a-9082-e4e664a5f1ff/talisman_faq_1-1.pdf) for reference), **yes**, you can assassinate creatures you encounter on cards you draw.

> Q1: Can the Assassin assassinate any creature, regardless of whether or not it is drawn from the Adventure deck or already faceup on the space when he encounters it?
>
> A: Yes.

Essentially you can always assassinate a creature you do battle with (i.e. has a strength value that you are choosing to engage in battle), unless the rules on some other card specify otherwise. Regarding pit fiends or the werewolf (or other board enemies like the sentinel, mutant, ice beasts, etc.), that seems like a separate question so I'd post that separately.

Comment: Is it really a separate questions? Aren't werewolf and pitfiends encounters handled like card-drawn/faceup encounters?

Comment: I think it would be a separate question, "Can board enemies be targeted the same way card enemies can?", since the results would go beyond the scope of the assassin's ability. This is just my opinion, though, so anyone who thinks otherwise feel free to chime in.

Comment: It's worth noting that only creatures that you attack in Battle (Strength-based Combat) can be assassinated, as creatures that you must attack in Psychic Combat use Craft instead, and the Assassinate ability explicitly only prevents adding a roll of the die to Strength. So Spirits, etc. cannot be assassinated.

Comment: This is very true: I'll update my answer.